# Count preceding-siblings of current node which contain a specific value

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-2.0

I'm writing an XSLT2.0 Stylesheet to transform an excel generated xml file into my own xml structure.

The structure of the generated xml is as following:

```
<Row><Cell><Data>##tablestart##</Data></Cell></Row>
<Row>
   <Cell><Data>1</Data></Cell>
   <Cell><Data>ABC</Data></Cell>
   <Cell><Data>DEF</Data></Cell>
   <Cell><Data>GHI</Data></Cell>
</Row>
<Row>
   <Cell><Data>2</Data></Cell>
   <Cell><Data>AC</Data></Cell>
   <Cell><Data>DF</Data></Cell>
   <Cell><Data>GI</Data></Cell>
</Row>
<Row>
   <Cell><Data>3</Data></Cell>
   <Cell><Data>AB</Data></Cell>
   <Cell><Data>DE</Data></Cell>
   <Cell><Data>GH</Data></Cell>
</Row>
<Row><Cell><Data>##tableclose##</Data></Cell></Row>
 some other rows I do not need...
<Row><Cell><Data>##tablestart##</Data></Cell></Row>...
```

This repeats multiple times.

Now I want to get the data between a tablestart and a tableclose.
For this I created an array containing all rows, now I want to add an attribute to each element which determines whether it is a data element (between a tablestart and tableclose or not) and handle it through checking this attribute in the following code.

The Question: How do I check whether it is between a tablestart and tableclose ?

I'm looking forward to reading your answeres :)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem that can be solved with XSLT 2.0 and `for-each-group select="Row" group-starting-with="Row[Cell/Data = '##tablestart##']"`:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="Row" group-starting-with="Row[Cell/Data = '##tablestart##']">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-ending-with="Row[Cell/Data = '##tableclose##']">
    <!-- now here current-group()[position() ne last()] selects the elements between start and and -->
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

If it is possible that the first `Row` does not have `Cell/Data = '##tablestart##'`, meaning there can be `Row`s before the first "table", then an additional check inside the for-each-group is needed.

Comment: Or you might want to use group-starting-with="Row[Cell/Data = ('##tablestart##', '##tableclose##')]" and then use xsl:choose to test within the group whether you are dealing with a group starting at a "start" or a group starting at a "close".

Answer (score 0):

You can ask XSLT to count the number of opening and closing tags that come before each Row.  If there are more opening tags than closing tags, you are in a data Row:

```
  <xsl:for-each select="//Row">
    <xsl:if test="Cell/Data != '##tableclose##' and count(preceding-sibling::Row[Cell/Data='##tablestart##']) != count(preceding-sibling::Row[Cell/Data='##tableclose##'])">
      Found an internal row at <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>      
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
```